# Product with same model to related products table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm getting crazy to create an insert to a table from a select of same model.
I think that I should create a temp table to elaborate all model, but how?
Here the table I have:

> Table product

```
+------------+----------+
| id_product | id_model |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | D        |
|          2 | D        |
|          3 | A        |
|          4 | C        |
|          5 | D        |
+------------+----------+
```

Here the table I would like to create, but my best problem is that the record in related should be duplicate like
**id1->id2** and **id2->id1**

> Table related

```
+------------+-----------------+
| id_product | related_product |
+------------+-----------------+
|          1 |               2 |
|          1 |               5 |
|          2 |               1 |
|          2 |               5 |
|          5 |               1 |
|          5 |               2 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think you just want a self-join

```
select p1.id_product, p2.id_product as related_product
from product p1 join
     product p2
     on p1.id_model = p2.id_model and
        p1.id_product <> p2.id_product;
```

Comment: One tiny change. I ran your query and the output is flipped. Swapping p1.id_product and p2.id_product on the first line will fix that. Other than that, great answer.

Comment: How can this be? The query which Gordon gave is symmetrical with respect to p1 and p2! Perhaps you have misunderstood something?

Comment: Voted up! But I still can't understand how it works. I've also added (just to create the table) `order by p1.id_product, p2.id_product ASC` and it works like a charm. Can you give me a bit of explanation? Two rows at least. Thanks in advance.